# AJAX sends data to controller, how do I update the correct id?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, eloquent

I am using ajax to post data to the controller and I need to update the record based on the id I pass through.  How would I go about this with Laravel Eloquent?  Here is the controller...I know the data is being passed to the controller correctly just don't know how to update based on the id I send.  Thank you for your help.

```
public function home(Request $request) {

$updateCus = New Customer($request->all());
$updateCus->update()->where('id', $request['id']);

}
```

Comment: mention what columns you are going to update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct syntax is:

```
Customer::where('id', $request->id)->update([
    'name' => $request->name,
    'country' => $request->country,
]);
```

Or, if you want to update many columns:

```
Customer::where('id', $request->id)->update($request->all());
```

Comment: To add to this, be aware of your model's `$guarded` or `$fillable` attributes, which may prevent you from updating some fields in mass assignment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update a record, you must fetch it from the database first. Instead, you're creating a new Customer. You should do something like this:

```
public function home(Request $request) {
    $customer = Customer::where('id', $request['id'])->first();
    if ($customer) {
        $customer->field1 = $request['field1'];
        //... update the fields you want to
        $customer->save();
    } else {
        //user not found...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function home(Request $request){
$id=$request->id;
$update=\DB:"table('tablename')->update(['columnname'=>$columname])->where('id',$id);
}
```

Comment: It's usually recommended that you add more context/explanation around code (as opposed to just having a code-only answer) as that makes the answer more useful.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)